# MongoDB aggregation $divide computed fields

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to compute a percentage in a MongoDB query based on computed fields - not sure if this is possible or not.  What I'd like to be able to do is calculate the failure percentage: `(failed count / total) * 100`

Here are a few sample documents:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52dda5afe4b0a491abb5407f"),
            "type" : "build",
            "time" : ISODate("2014-01-20T22:39:43.880Z"),
            "data" : {
                    "buildNumber" : 30,
                    "buildResult" : "SUCCESS"
            }
    },
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52dd9fede4b0a491abb5407a"),
            "type" : "build",
            "time" : ISODate("2014-01-20T22:15:07.901Z"),
            "data" : {
                    "buildNumber" : 4,
                    "buildResult" : "FAILURE"
            }
    },
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52dda153e4b0a491abb5407b"),
            "type" : "build",
            "time" : ISODate("2014-01-20T22:21:07.790Z"),
            "data" : {
                    "buildNumber" : 118,
                    "buildResult" : "SUCCESS"
            }
    }
```

Here is the query I am trying to work with.  The issue is in the FailPercent/$divide line:

```
db.col.aggregate([    
    { $match: { "data.buildResult" : { $ne : null } } },
    { $group: {          
        _id: {              
            month: { $month: "$time" },             
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },             
            year: { $year: "$time" },                       
        },         
        Aborted: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "ABORTED"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Failure: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "FAILURE"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Unstable: { $sum: { $cond : [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "UNSTABLE"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Success: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "SUCCESS"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Total: { $sum: 1 },
        FailPercent: { $divide: [ "Failure", "Total" ] }
    } },     
    { $sort: { "_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1 } } 
])
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You almost got it.  Only change that would be required is that you'll have to compute the `FailPercent` in an additional `project` phase, because the total is only available after the completion of the `group` phase.  Try this:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([    
    { $match: { "data.buildResult" : { $ne : null } } },
    { $group: {          
        _id: {              
            month: { $month: "$time" },             
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },             
            year: { $year: "$time" },                       
        },         
        Aborted: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "ABORTED"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Failure: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "FAILURE"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Unstable: { $sum: { $cond : [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "UNSTABLE"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Success: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$data.buildResult", "SUCCESS"]}, 1, 0]} },
        Total: { $sum: 1 }
    } }, 
    {$project:{Aborted:1, Failure:1, Unstable:1, Success:1, Total:1, FailPercent: { $divide: [ "$Failure", "$Total" ]}}},
    { $sort: { "_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1 } } 
])
```

Comment: Other examples try to use multiple groupings which doesn't work for all cases and is not as elegant.  This is nice!

Comment: Great example !